# MKMapView memory issues in ios7 sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, mkmapview, mapkit

i have MKMapView in a view controller and when i starts zooming on it consume a lot of memory 
and when i leave the view who contains the MKMapView the memory is not released (I am using ARC in my App)

**Edit**:

i read in some stack overflow answers that i have to put the MKMapView  in AppDelegate :

```
-(MKMapView*) mapView
{
    if(_mapView == nil) {
        _mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
    }
    return _mapView;
}
```

and in viewWillDisappear of viewController that contains the MKMapView put

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    XAppDelegate.mapView.delegate = nil;
    [XAppDelegate.mapView removeFromSuperview];

}
```

but it did not resolve my problem.

Comment: Testing on simulator or device?

Comment: device(ipad air ios 7)

Comment: It is a good practice to have a single instance throughout your app, as long as only have no more than one map per view. You can save memory, but it's not mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common flaw I've seen is that the MKOverlay is holding a strong reference to the `MKOverlayView`/`MKOverlayRender` and the `MKMapView`. This causes a retain cycle because the `MKMapView` holds a strong reference to the `MKOverlay` instances as well.

Comment: but I haven't drawn a MKOverlay i have just an empty map and when i starts zooming it consume a lot of memory

Comment: Maps are memory intensive. You'll never change that. What you must ensure is that you can reclaim that memory when it's deallocated. In general, _nothing_ should have a strong reference to a MKMapView, unless you're using a singleton pattern. This includes the containing view controller. It should only be retained because it is a subview to your root view. Once the root view is deallocated, it should be as well.